# gnome-panel context menu missing

Tags: 14.04, compiz, gnome-panel, context-menu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome-Flashback (Compiz).
I believe that I messed up gnome-panel when replacing Rhythmbox with Clementine.
Now I cannot get context menu to add/remove/move launchers from my top and bottom panels.
No key combinations work (Alt+RightMouseClick, Alt+Super+RightMouseClick...).

Actually it works, but I get following options; Minimize, Maximize, Move, Resize, (separator), Always On Top, Always On Visible Workspace, Only On This Workspace, Move To Another Workspace, (separator), Close.
It seems that current window has focus over gnome-panel.
No commands related to reseting/restarting gnome-panel works.
Completely removing Gnome-Flashback and reinstalling did not help.

You are my last hope before I do clean install of OS, but lots of programs, some like Android Studio, are very customized and I am very reluctant to do that.

Edit :
Created new user and it is OK. Will try to find difference in configuration files... Or just switch to new user.

Thank you in advance!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Creating new user was a way to resolve everything.
First created new user, then deleting old user (preserving files, renamed old user home folder), then re-creating old user... uid and gid were automatically 1000 so no problems here.

While customizing OS UI, I stumbled upon the core problem again, and although I cannot be 100% sure and cannot reproduce it no longer, there was a stage when certain button combinations in Compiz configuration settings manager (Expo, Desktop Wall... ) caused not to be able to get context menu on gnome-panel. I have disabled everything that I do not use and deleted shortcuts/buttons.